# Reduce an associative array to randomised pairs of unique values

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, unique, reduction

I am trying to reduce an associative array to pairs of unique values, whereby the keys are letters to be paired and the values are their `count()`s.

Each pair cannot contain the same letter twice such as `AA` or `BB`.

It is permissible for more than one occurrence of the same pair.
e.g. `AC`, `DC`, `AC`, `DC` are all valid in the resultant array

Every time a letter is picked, its associated number decreases by one until none remain, or

any odd/leftover letters should be flagged and not ignored, e.g. `Array([paired]=>Array(...) [unpaired]=>Array(...))`

Sample input:

```
Array(
    [A] => 8
    [B] => 16
    [C] => 15
    [D] => 4
    [E] => 1
)
```

Possible output:

```
[
    'paired' => [
        'BD', 'AE', 'BC', 'AC', 'BC', ...
    ],
    'unpaired' => [
        'C' => 4
    ]
]
```

I would prefer two unique letters to be chosen at random, but if that is too hard then the resultant array should be easily `shuffle()`-able

I have tried various combinations of `array_reduce()`, `array_map()`, `array_walk()`, `array_unique()` etc., even Pear's `Math_Combinatorics`, but all to no avail.

Comment: Im assuming you want a function here, maybe you could add some examples of what the expected result would be.  myFunc(<some Array definition>) = <the exact expected result>

Comment: yes, either a function or a combination of inbuilt array functions. the expected result would be an array of strings with two different letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that will generate the results you want. It iterates over the `letters` array, filtering out letters which have been completely used, until there is only one letter which is unused. The list of pairs and the unused letter are then returned in an array:

```
function random_pairs($letters) {
    $pairs = array();
    $letters = array_filter($letters);
    while (count($letters) > 1) {
        $keys = array_keys($letters);
        shuffle($keys);
        list($letter1, $letter2) = array_slice($keys, 0, 2);
        $pairs[] = "$letter1$letter2";
        $letters[$letter1]--;
        $letters[$letter2]--;
        $letters = array_filter($letters);
    }
    return array('pairs' => $pairs, 'unpaired' => $letters);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$letters = array('A' => 8, 'B' => 16, 'C' => 15, 'D' => 4, 'E' => 1);
print_r(random_pairs($letters));
```

Sample output:

```
Array
(
    [pairs] => Array
        (
            [0] => CB
            [1] => CE
            [2] => CD
            [3] => BD
            [4] => CB
            [5] => DC
            [6] => AB
            [7] => CA
            [8] => DA
            [9] => BC
            [10] => BA
            [11] => BA
            [12] => AB
            [13] => BA
            [14] => BC
            [15] => AB
            [16] => BC
            [17] => CB
            [18] => CB
            [19] => CB
            [20] => CB
        )
    [unpaired] => Array
        (
            [C] => 2
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Q6NKN)

Comment: thank you so much - this is great! I was wondering - since sometimes the unpaired array is empty when the function manages to pair all the letters, and sometimes it is not empty - would it take much modification to ensure that it is always empty if mathematically possible, i.e. if perfect pairings CAN exist?

Comment: @verb please do not extend your question requirements.  If you have a new requirement, ask a new question.

Comment: @verbumSapienti that would require a far more in-depth parsing of the input array to determine if it was possible to do that, and the pairs would have to be constructed algorithmically, not randomly. If that's what you actually want, you should ask another question as it is far beyond the scope of this one.

Comment: @mickmackusa I did not extend the requirements

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive technique.   It uses `array_rand()` to grab two unique keys at a time.  If you need the paired keys to be randomly arranged, then call `shuffle()` upon them.  What I mean is, `shuffle()` might be omittable depending on your expectations.

An advantage in using `array_rand()` is that `array_keys()` doesn't need to be called since it returns random keys.

I have deliberately designed this snippet to unconditionally declare the `unpaired` subarray -- even if it is empty.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/v0btr))

```
function randomPairs(array $letters, array $result = []) {
    if (count($letters) < 2) {
        $result['unpaired'] = $letters;
        return $result;
    }
    $keys = array_rand($letters, 2);
    shuffle($keys);
    $result['paired'][] = $keys[0] . $keys[1];
    --$letters[$keys[0]];
    --$letters[$keys[1]];
    return randomPairs(array_filter($letters), $result);
}
```

Without recursion: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/f0sZv))

```
function randomPairs(array $letters): array {
    $result['paired'] = [];
    while (count($letters) > 1) {
       $keys = array_rand($letters, 2);
       shuffle($keys);
       $result['paired'][] = $keys[0] . $keys[1];
       --$letters[$keys[0]];
       --$letters[$keys[1]];
       $letters = array_filter($letters);
    }
    $result['unpaired'] = $letters;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: @verb I haven't thought very long about your question extension, but consuming the letter with the largest count (on every new iteration), then giving it a random partner value seems to work in my tests. https://3v4l.org/abs9J

Comment: I was thinking the same thing overnight, but didn't feel the need to make the effort given OPs lack of response to two good answers to the original question...

Comment: (I was riding a stationary bike while browsing SO yesterday, so I took a quick shot at it 
 -- was curious of how I would do it, frankly)

Comment: Just quietly, I wonder why your answer was deemed to be helpful, but mine was not.  I may never understand this place.

Comment: No idea on that one. I've often felt that my answers are invisible - there have been questions where OP has had an in-depth conversation with someone whose answer didn't work, and completely ignored my answer which had a working demo...

Comment: sheesh, what's with the rush? I will test in my own time thanks

Comment: @verb I wasn't rushing you.  I did answer your requirement extension (how to prioritize keys of greater values). May I ask why you accepted Nicks answer which makes more function calls than mine?  Is my answer confusing? Is it unclear about its advantage?  I have used a `shuffle()` call, but it might not be necessary depending on how you want the two letters to be paired as a concatenated string.

Answer (score -1):

I propose you this one :

I've just seen Nick's answer, but it do 15 minutes i'm trying xD I want to post my answer :p

Based on a "pickRandomValues" function, i made it dynamic, and you can as well choose the number of letters you want

```
function pickRandom(&$array = [], $count = 1) {
    $valuesFound = [];
    if (count($array) >= $count) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $index = rand(0, count($array) - 1);
            $tmp = array_splice($array, $index, 1);
            $valuesFound[] = $tmp[0];
        }
    }
    return $valuesFound;
}
```

And you body code

```
$tmpArr = [];
foreach ($a as $letter => $count) {
  $t = [];
  $tmpArr = array_merge($tmpArr, array_pad($t, $count, $letter));
}

$pairs = [];
while (count($tmpArr) >= $numberOfLetters) {
    $pick = pickRandom($tmpArr, $numberOfLetters);
    $pairs[] = implode($pick);
}

$finalArray = [
    "paired" => $pairs,
    "unpaired" => array_count_values($tmpArr)
];
```

So, it give something like this :

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b143396b7267bd6029ff613746d6c047557a282

Comment: This does not provide the desired result.